# Ngrok can't get session and cookies

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, ngrok

My ngrok can't get cookies and session after forwarding my local port,

```
ngrok http --host-header=rewrite 5000
```

if I try in local the cookies and session work normally but if I forward to ngrok and someone with react app access it the cookies and session not appear on the browser

here my cors config :

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors({
  origin: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Accept', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'X-Access-Token', 'X-Key', 'Cookies', 'Cache-Control', 'Set-Cookie', ],
  credentials: true
}));
```

I try to store cookies and session after user login,
here login controller :

```
export const login = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  
  const schema = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().email().required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  });
  const { error } = schema.validate(req.body);
  if (error) return res.status(400).json(errorRespone(error.details[0].message));

  const user = await Manager.findOneBy(User,{email : email});

  if(!user) return res.status(404).json(errorRespone(`User with email ${email} not found`));
  if(user.is_verified === false ) return res.status(404).json(errorRespone(`User with email ${email} not verified`));

  const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
  if(!checkPassword) return res.status(400).json({msg : "Password not match"})

  const payload = {user_id : user._id, email : user.email, nama: user.nama, role: user.role};
  const accessToken = accessTokenSign(payload, "30m");
  const refreshToken = refreshTokenSign(payload,"1d");

  try {
    await Manager.update(User, {_id : user._id}, {refresh_token : refreshToken})

    res.cookie("refresh_token", refreshToken, {
       httpOnly : true,
       maxAge : 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
       sameSite : "none",
       secure : true
    })

    const loginUser = {
      email : user.email,
      nama : user.nama,
      role : user.role,
      is_verified : user.is_verified
    }

    req.session["user_id"] = user._id


    res.status(200).json(respone("Success login", { accessToken, user : loginUser }));
   
  } catch (error) {
    if(error) return res.status(500).json(errorRespone(error.message))
  }
}
```

but if user touch logout, the server emit 401 status code which is unauthorize
here logout controller :

```
export const logout = async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const user_id = req.session['user_id'];
  console.log("session logout : "+user_id);
  
  if(!user_id) return res.status(401).json(errorRespone("Login first to access this feature"));

  try {
    await Manager.update(User, {_id : new ObjectId(user_id)}, {refresh_token : ""})
    res.clearCookie("refresh_token");
    res.status(200).json(respone("Success logout",{}));
  } catch (error) {
    if(error) return res.status(500).json(errorRespone(error.message))
  }

}
```